# How can I use Foundation's URLRequest type on Linux?

Tags: swift, linux, swift5

When I try to use the struct [URLRequest from Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest), I get an error when compiling with swift 5.1.1. The same code works fine with swift 5.0.1.

Example: given file Foo.swift with content

```
import Foundation
print(URLRequest.self)
```

With Swift 5.0.1 we get

```
$ docker run --rm -v "$PWD:/app" swift:5.0.1 sh -c \
     'swiftc /app/Foo.swift && ./Foo'
URLRequest
```

But with 5.1.1

```
$ docker run --rm -v "$PWD:/app" swift:5.1.1 sh -c \
     'swiftc /app/Foo.swift && ./Foo
Foo.swift:2:7: error: use of unresolved identifier 'URLRequest'
print(URLRequest.self)
      ^~~~~~~~~~
```

I can't seem to find anything mentioning relevant changes to Foundation, and the source code at https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation looks stable, too.

What's going on here, and is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is caused by a [recent move](https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-move-urlsession-to-new-foundationnetworking-module/14002/25) of networking related objects into a new **FoundationNetworking** module.  The new module does not exists on Darwin, so one must use preprocessor commands to make code work on all supported platforms:

```swift
import Foundation
#if canImport(FoundationNetworking)
import FoundationNetworking
#endif

print(URLRequest.self)
```

This code compiles fine with both docker commands given above.

Comment: For anyone interested, as of December 2023, this is still an ongoing issue on Linux.